# How would you specify mixed boundary conditions for a 2D PDE in the matrix used for finite differences

Tags: pde, finite-difference, boundary-conditions

I have the following PDE in 2D:

$U_{x} + U_{xx} + U_y + U_{yy} + U_{xy} = f$

where $f$ is a constant.

And I'm trying to create a matrix $A$ to solve the PDE through finite differences: $AU = f$. I will invert $A$ such that $U = A^{-1}f$.

I have mixed boundary conditions in this form:

$0 = a_0U + a_1U_{x} + a_2U_{xx} + a_3U_y + a_4U_{yy} + a_5U_{xy}$

I'm just not sure how I could specify or code this BC equation into my matrix. I did a lot of searching but most of the tutorials are for 1d equations only. I know about the ghost point method but I have only done it for $0 = a_0U + a_1U_{x}$. However, I'm not sure what I should do when it comes to the point at $f(x_1, y_1)$, since it would involve multiple ghost points ($f(x_0,y_1), f(x_1,y_0)$, etc.).

Separately, should $a_{0, ..., 5}$ be a function of $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Any derivative can be expressed as a linear combination of an appropriate 'stencil' of points around the current one of interest. At the boundary, you can use ghost points to do this and the FD system is written in terms of all points - ghost and interior. In the case of Dirichlet BC, you probably skip the equations for the boundary because they are trivial - it is imposing a value. For mixed BC, they are evaluated as part of solution to the system.

Comment: @gpavanb How would I use ghost points for the boundary condition at $f(x_1, y_1)$? Since in the mixed boundary condition equation I have derivatives with respect to both X and Y so I would involve two ghost points. I'm not sure how to write these two points as a function of the interior points.

Comment: You would indeed and in fact, even more than those ghost points if you wish to approximate the BCs more accurately! Make sure you have enough number of boundary conditions to ensure a unique solution to the problem.

Comment: Seeing a second order in the boundary conditions is a bit unusual. Are you sure about that?